# Trying to return HTML in an ActionResult results in a HTTP 406 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to return HTML in an `ActionResult`. I have already tried:

```
[Produces("text/html")]
public ActionResult DisplayWebPage()
{
    return Content("<html><p><i>Hello! You are trying to view <u>something!</u></i></p></html>");
}
```

This displays nothing in the `<iframe>`. I have tried:

```
[Produces("text/html")]
public string DisplayWebPage()
{
    return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("<html><p><i>Hello! You are trying to view <u>something!</u></i></p></html>");
}
```

Microsoft Edge gives me the following message:

> **HTTP 406 error**
>   This page isn’t speaking our language
>   Microsoft Edge can’t display this page because it wasn’t in a format that can be shown.

Firefox and Chrome refuse to display anything. I have also tried `HtmlEncode` and the normal `ActionResult`. Here is the segment for my `<iframe>` in my View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <iframe src="/Home/DisplayWebPage" class="col-sm-12"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why am I not receiving any results? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Works fine in mvc-5 (cannot test in core-mvc at the moment). Have you tried removing the `[Produces]` attribute?

Comment: Try to add `body` tag

Comment: your html content is missing the structure thats why the error is causing try to send a valid html conten

Comment: I have tried removing `[Produces]`, still no luck

Comment: Even if I use the correct structure for an HTML page, it still doesn't render.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Produces("text/html")` will not have any effect because there is no built-in output formatter for HTML.

To fix your problem just specify content type explicitly:

```
public ActionResult DisplayWebPage()
{
    return Content("<html><p><i>Hello! You are trying to view <u>something!</u></i></p></html>", "text/html");
}
```

Another option is to change return type of your action to `string` and request `text/html` format via `Accept` header. See [Introduction to formatting response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting) for the details.

Comment: Yes! It works perfectly! I should've tried to pass `text/html` as a parameter of `Content` instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

There are two ways to do this:
**1.** Update Action to:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var content = "<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1><p>Some text</p></body></html>";
    return new ContentResult()
    {
        Content = content,
        ContentType = "text/html",
    };
}
```

**2.** Update Action to:

```
[Produces("text/html")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Ok("<html><p><i>Hello! You are trying to view <u>something!</u></i></p></html>");
}
```

and update AddMvc line in startup.cs to:

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.OutputFormatters.Add(new HtmlOutputFormatter()));
```

where HtmlOutputFormatter is:

```
public class HtmlOutputFormatter : StringOutputFormatter
{
    public HtmlOutputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add("text/html");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed approach. CodeFuller's answer was much shorter and cleaner which is why I selected his answer. +1 anyway! ;-)

Comment: Yes, his answer is short but mine is generic. Just make Produces tag work.